# SQL COUNT with MIN Date

Tags: sql

I am setting up on time delivery tracking from purchase orders through our ERP system. I am working with three different tables within that system When our receiving department enters a date, I can compare it against the due date - the problem is, our accounting will sometimes want to adjust the information and then causes another (or multiple) entry in the table and a simple count query will include those dates - thus giving bad information.

My Query is this:

```
 SELECT        COUNT(PO_Receipts.ORDNUM_55) AS OrderCount
             , SUM(CASE WHEN TNXDTE_55 = CURDUE_10 THEN 1
                   ELSE 0 END) AS On_Time
             , SUM(CASE WHEN TNXDTE_55 < CURDUE_10 THEN 1
                   ELSE 0 END) AS Early
             , SUM(CASE WHEN TNXDTE_55 > CURDUE_10 THEN 1
                   ELSE 0 END) AS Pastdue
 FROM          PO_Receipts
               INNER JOIN Order_Master
                 ON PO_Receipts.TYPE_55 = Order_Master.TYPE_10 
                 AND PO_Receipts.ORDNUM_55 = Order_Master.ORDNUM_10 
                 AND PO_Receipts.LINNUM_55 = Order_Master.LINNUM_10
                 AND PO_Receipts.DELNUM_55 = Order_Master.DELNUM_10 
                 AND PO_Receipts.PRTNUM_55 = Order_Master.PRTNUM_10
               INNER JOIN Part_Master
                 ON Order_Master.PRTNUM_10 = Part_Master.PRTNUM_01
WHERE          (Order_Master.TYPE_10 <> 'NI') 
               AND (PO_Receipts.TNXDTE_55 >= 
                    DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0))
               AND (PO_Receipts.TNXDTE_55 < 
                    DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
               AND (Part_Master.INSRQD_01 = 'Y')
```

Here is one sample of the data returned (removing the COUNTs and aliases so I can see what is being counted)

```
ORDNUM_55 |LINNUM_55| DELNUM_55| TNXDTE_55 | PRTNUM_55| CURDUE_10 | 
:---------|:--------|:---------|:----------|:---------|:----------|
70029239    01       01          8/18/2017  CBL1592    8/18/2017
70029239    01       01          8/18/2017  CBL1592    8/18/2017 
70029239    02       01          8/18/2017  CBL1593    8/18/2017 
70029239    02       01          8/18/2017  CBL1593    8/18/2017 
70029239    02       02          8/15/2017  CBL1593    8/18/2017 
70029239    02       02          8/15/2017  CBL1593    8/18/2017 
70029239    02       02          8/17/2017  CBL1593    8/18/2017 
70029239    02       02          8/17/2017  CBL1593    8/18/2017
```

And here is what I would like (again, COUNTs removed for clarity)

```
ORDNUM_55 |LINNUM_55| DELNUM_55| TNXDTE_55 | PRTNUM_55| CURDUE_10 | 
:---------|:--------|:---------|:----------|:---------|:----------|
70029239    01       01          8/18/2017  CBL1592    8/18/2017
70029239    02       02          8/15/2017  CBL1593    8/18/2017
```

I assume I would use MIN(TNXDTE_55) but I don't know how in a COUNT statement
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: you should tag the rdbms you are using.

Comment: Can you post the SQL after removing the counts?

Comment: sure @justiceorjustus - I added it to my original question - I think that's what I'm supposed to do

Comment: @AlanRobertson what is your RDBMS? SQL SERVER? MySQL? other?

Comment: @AlanRobertson To be honest, that database is weird. What datatype is `TNXDTE_55`? Also, in your desired results: why was `CBL1582` chosen over `CBL1583`? Based on it being a lower number? There's more at play here to decide which is the `MIN(Date)` than just the date. Do the values of other fields help your decision on which to choose?

Comment: It seems that the RDBMS is SQL Server since one of the samples include getdate(), datediff() and dateadd().

Comment: sorry everybody - the RDBMS is SQL Server - thought I selected that when I initiated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the sample output I understand that you need to obtain the rows for a given ORDNUM_55 that have different values of PRTNUM_55, and if there is more that one row for a given PRTNUM_55 you need to obtain the one with the minimum date. Also it seems that you are using SQL Server since you are using getdate() and datediff().

In that case you can use `EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT PO_Receipts.ORDNUM_55,PO_Receipts.LINNUM_55, 
       PO_Receipts.DELNUM_55, PO_Receipts.TNXDTE_55, 
       PO_Receipts.PRTNUM_55, Order_Master.CURDUE_10
FROM PO_Receipts 
INNER JOIN Order_Master
   ON PO_Receipts.ORDNUM_55 = Order_Master.ORDNUM_10
WHERE (PO_Receipts.ORDNUM_55 = '70029239')
  AND (Order_Master.DUEQTY_10 = 0)
  AND (PO_Receipts.TNXQTY_55 > 0)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PO_Receipts AS ReceiptsTemp
      -- conditions for joining the rows
      WHERE ReceiptsTemp.ORDNUM_55=PO_Receipts.ORDNUM_55
        AND ReceiptsTemp.PRTNUM_55=PO_Receipts.PRTNUM_55
      -- conditions for the filter logic
        AND ReceiptsTemp.TNXDTE_55<PO_Receipts.TNXDTE_55)
```

This searchs for the rows with the same ORDNUM and PRTNUM and only returns the ones with the minimum date, but note that if two or more rows within the same ORDNUM/PRTNUM have the minimum date it will return all of them.

If you need only one row for each ORDNUM/PRTNUM, then you need to perform one or more extra steps depending on the nature of the data:

1. Add an additional condition, for example, when the minimun date is the same returns the row with the minimum DELNUM (note that you can use INNER JOIN in the `EXISTS` subquery if you want to use fields of Order_Master for the extra filtering):

   ```
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PO_Receipts AS ReceiptsTemp
     -- conditions for joining the rows
     WHERE ReceiptsTemp.ORDNUM_55=PO_Receipts.ORDNUM_55
       AND ReceiptsTemp.PRTNUM_55=PO_Receipts.PRTNUM_55
     -- conditions for what you want
       AND (ReceiptsTemp.TNXDTE_55<PO_Receipts.TNXDTE_55
            OR (ReceiptsTemp.TNXDTE_55=PO_Receipts.TNXDTE_55
                AND ReceiptsTemp.DELNUM_55<PO_Receipts.DELNUM_55)))
   ```
2. Use `(SELECT DISTINCT ...) AS Subquery` for eliminating exact duplicates and then group using the results of the subquery:

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(PO_Receipts.ORDNUM_55) AS OrderCount, <other aggregates>
   FROM (
     SELECT PO_Receipts.ORDNUM_55,PO_Receipts.LINNUM_55, 
            PO_Receipts.DELNUM_55, PO_Receipts.TNXDTE_55, 
            PO_Receipts.PRTNUM_55, Order_Master.CURDUE_10
     FROM PO_Receipts 
     INNER JOIN Order_Master
        ON PO_Receipts.ORDNUM_55 = Order_Master.ORDNUM_10
     WHERE (PO_Receipts.ORDNUM_55 = '70029239')
       AND (Order_Master.DUEQTY_10 = 0)
       AND (PO_Receipts.TNXQTY_55 > 0)
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PO_Receipts AS ReceiptsTemp
           -- conditions for joining the rows
           WHERE ReceiptsTemp.ORDNUM_55=PO_Receipts.ORDNUM_55
             AND ReceiptsTemp.PRTNUM_55=PO_Receipts.PRTNUM_55
           -- conditions for the filter logic
             AND (ReceiptsTemp.TNXDTE_55<PO_Receipts.TNXDTE_55
                  OR (ReceiptsTemp.TNXDTE_55=PO_Receipts.TNXDTE_55
                      AND ReceiptsTemp.DELNUM_55<PO_Receipts.DELNUM_55)))
   ) AS DistinctRows
   GROUP BY <group condition>
   ```

Comment: Thank you @ Alberto Martinez - your great explanation and code helped tremendously!